# Flexslider custom controls won't work right

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, flexslider

I'm building a slider in wordpress using flexslider.
I managed to create custom buttons, but they only work one image forward and one back. Its weird and I can't figure out where the problem is. The default buttons work just fine.
My code:

**Scripts.js**

```
$('.flexslider-post-page').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: true,
    directionNav: false, 
    controlsContainer: ".projects-buttons-container",
    manualControls: $(".projects-buttons-container a"),

  });
```

**the buttons HTML**

```
<div class="projects-buttons-container">
  <a class="prev" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="next" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```